# Can't get the exact DataTables theme like on their website!

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datatables

I started using DataTables which is a jquery plugin. I followed all the instructions carefully, and the table is working nice, but with theme problems. I am trying to get the exact style as on their website demo.

Here are the styles am including:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/public/js/DataTables/media/css/demo_table.css">

<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/public/js/jqueryui/css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.8.13.custom.css">
```

And here are the scripts:

```
<script src="/public/javascripts/jquery-1.5.2.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>



<script src="/public/js/DataTables/media/js/jquery.dataTables.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

</script>

<script src="/public/js/jqueryui/js/jquery-ui-1.8.13.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
```

And I use jquery like:

```
 $(function(){
        var oTable = $('#myTable').dataTable({
            "bJQueryUI": true,
        });
```

And here is what I get:
![enter image description here][1]

I am trying to get the same look as the table in that page:

http://www.datatables.net/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should also add the option "sPaginationType": "full_numbers".

Try like this:

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
    "bJQueryUI": true,
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers"
} );
```

If the problem are the colors, those depend from the Jquery UI theme you have downloaded. I think on datatables.net they use the theme 'Smoothness'...anyway, look [here](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/#ffDefault=Verdana,Arial,sans-serif&fwDefault=normal&fsDefault=1.1em&cornerRadius=4px&bgColorHeader=cccccc&bgTextureHeader=03_highlight_soft.png&bgImgOpacityHeader=75&borderColorHeader=aaaaaa&fcHeader=222222&iconColorHeader=222222&bgColorContent=ffffff&bgTextureContent=01_flat.png&bgImgOpacityContent=75&borderColorContent=aaaaaa&fcContent=222222&iconColorContent=222222&bgColorDefault=e6e6e6&bgTextureDefault=02_glass.png&bgImgOpacityDefault=75&borderColorDefault=d3d3d3&fcDefault=555555&iconColorDefault=888888&bgColorHover=dadada&bgTextureHover=02_glass.png&bgImgOpacityHover=75&borderColorHover=999999&fcHover=212121&iconColorHover=454545&bgColorActive=ffffff&bgTextureActive=02_glass.png&bgImgOpacityActive=65&borderColorActive=aaaaaa&fcActive=212121&iconColorActive=454545&bgColorHighlight=fbf9ee&bgTextureHighlight=02_glass.png&bgImgOpacityHighlight=55&borderColorHighlight=fcefa1&fcHighlight=363636&iconColorHighlight=2e83ff&bgColorError=fef1ec&bgTextureError=02_glass.png&bgImgOpacityError=95&borderColorError=cd0a0a&fcError=cd0a0a&iconColorError=cd0a0a&bgColorOverlay=aaaaaa&bgTextureOverlay=01_flat.png&bgImgOpacityOverlay=0&opacityOverlay=30&bgColorShadow=aaaaaa&bgTextureShadow=01_flat.png&bgImgOpacityShadow=0&opacityShadow=30&thicknessShadow=8px&offsetTopShadow=-8px&offsetLeftShadow=-8px&cornerRadiusShadow=8px)